# Exception has occurred, unexpected character at char 1

Tags: json, flutter

I've been struggling with this for quite a while. I'm just trying to read text from JSON and place it in Text, but it won't allow me, and it only throws out this error which I can't find a solution to.
Error :

[image]

I made a separate class quotes.dart which contains only this

```
  final String author;
  final String quote;

  Quotes({required this.author, required this.quote});

  factory Quotes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Quotes(author: data["author"], quote: data["quote"]);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "author": author,
      "quote": quote,
    };
  }
}
```

And in main I've got this:

```
// ignore_for_file: unnecessary_string_interpolations
import 'quotes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:todo_task/quotes.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: todo_task(),
  ));
}

class todo_task extends StatefulWidget {
  const todo_task({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _todo_taskState createState() => _todo_taskState();
}

class _todo_taskState extends State<todo_task> {
  Map<String, dynamic> userMap = jsonDecode('assets/json/quotes.json');
  // user = Quotes.fromJson(userMap);
.
.
.
Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 110.0, 5.0, 0.0),
                  child: Text('${userMap['author']}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      )),
                )),
```

Also, my JSON file is simple

```
{
"author":"Albert Einstein",
"quote":"We cannot solve problems with the kind of thinking we employed when we came up with them."
}
```

Comment: `jsonDecode` does not accept a file path. It accepts the JSON string, itself. You need to read the contents of the file first, then pass those contents into the decoder.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)